# Find XOR from Addition

Tags: arithmetic, boolean-algebra, binary

Consider the following.

`A^B^C^D` and  `A + B + C + D`

(^ represents bitwise operation XOR)

You are given `A + B + C + D`, and you have to find `A^B^C^D`. I know there is the relation between XOR and Addition but I unable to figure out how to utilise this fact. I am not even sure if it's the right direction to think. So, my question is how do I do this?

Also, I don't get how XOR is used to find addition. I tried searching on google, but it's too sophisticated to understand. I couldn't find a layman approach for the same. If you guys can explain in layman's terms.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "addition"? What are the data types of $A,B,C,D$?

Comment: @BenGrossmann A, B, C, D are whole numbers. And addition is 'plus' operation like 1+1 = 2.

Comment: so if $A,B$ are whole numbers, what exactly do you mean by $A \wedge B$? Is that a bitwise XOR? For example, what is $13 \wedge 7$?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes.

Comment: The connection is that that bitwise XOR can be used to implement addition. In particular, combining a bitwise XOR with a bitwise OR gives us a [half-adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics))

Comment: Yeah, I read that. But I am confused how do I backtrack that to get my answer. Like how do I remove carry part from my sum(A+B+C+D) to get my answer? @BenGrossmann

Comment: Why do you believe that there is a way to do this?

Comment: @BenGrossmann I am being optimistic. There's a code competition going, I solved and reduced the question to this extent. So, Solving this might give my answer. I am not sure if there's a way or not :)

Comment: @BenGrossmann But as a previous bit affects the next bit. so, there might be a solution to this problem

Comment: All right. Well, it's easy to see that this is impossible. Looking at the two-number case: if you are given $A + B$, it is impossible to recover $A \wedge B$. For example, suppose that $A + B = 5$. We could have
$$
A = 0, B = 5 \text{ or } A=1,B=4 \implies A \wedge B = 5,\\
A = 2, B = 3 \implies A \wedge B = 1.
$$
It is impossible to know which value for $A \wedge B$ is correct using only $A + B$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann well, I guess this answers my question. please add this in the answer part. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you're looking for is impossible. Looking at the two-number case: if you are given $A+B$, it is impossible to recover $A \wedge B$. For example, suppose that $A + B = 5$. We could have
$$
A = 0, B = 5 \text{ or } A=1,B=4 \implies A \wedge B = 5,\\ A = 2, B = 3 \implies A \wedge B = 1.
$$
It is impossible to know which value for $A \wedge B$ is correct using only $A+B$.